# Why index error: list out of range is coming?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

For the function below I'm getting the error which

```
line 499, in export_xls
    datas['form'] = self.read(['start_date', 'end_date'])[0]
```

The code is:

```
@api.multi
def export_xls(self):
    context = self._context
    datas = {'ids': context.get('active_ids', [])}
    datas['model'] = 'wizard.stock.history'
    datas['form'] = self.read(['start_date', 'end_date'])[0]
    for field in datas['form'].keys():
        if isinstance(datas['form'][field], tuple):
            datas['form'][field] = datas['form'][field]
    if context.get('xls_export'):
        return self.env.ref('product_category_report.stock_xlsx').report_action(self, data=datas)
```

I'm taking stock report from odoo 11. For that purpose I have created a wizard and passing values. Now the error comes like this.

Comment: check the output of `self.read(['start_date', 'end_date'])`, error is because toy are trying to access the first element of an `empty list`.

Comment: Can you please let me know what is the solution?

Comment: you can check if the function returns a blank or not before slicing. `someVariable = self.read(['start_date', 'end_date'])   if someVariable: datas['form'] = someVariable[0]` also include the for loop inside the `if`. You may also want to include an `else`,  if your  `if someVariable ` fails (blank list), otherwise you will not have `'form'` key in your `datas' dictionary